# Keep encountering these errors when trying to install discordjs/opus

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install, opus

I am trying to create a discord music bot using Node js, in which I need to install @discordjs/opus.
Upon trying the command
`npm install @discordjs/opus`
I get the following error:

https://pastebin.com/HDm5FZST

Comment: I think i've narrowed the error down to: 
``` fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config.h': No such file or directory  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you having trouble with build tools try

**Note:** first you need to install python,after that run this(admin powershell)

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools && npm install -g node-gyp
```

If it not solve your problem I would like suggest you to using `opusscript` or `node-opus` instead